# Possible to integrate Azure Application insights with existing service fabric cluster in code-less manner?

Tags: performance-testing, azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights, azure-web-app-service, azure-monitoring

Would like to use Application insights especially, "Azure live metrics stream" feature on existing PROD Azure service fabric workloads to do performance analysis.Is service fabric has built-in integration with Azure Application Insights?

Is it possible do it in code less manner like how Application insights can be enabled via portal for web Apps/Azure functions? If not, why?

Then, how to do it code based manner? Any reference to do code changes would be helpful.

What is the difference between code less & code based monitoring? When to choose one over another? Our requirement is to study performance of application (deployed on various nodes of PROD service fabric cluster) under different load.

Please clarify above list of queries.

Comment: Some quick response would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. *Is service fabric has built-in integration with Azure Application Insights?*

You could leverage Windows Azure Diagnostics (WAD) extension to sink SF cluster logs and/or Perf metrics into App Insights - [Configuring Application Insights with WAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-event-aggregation-wad#send-logs-to-application-insights)

There is no way to monitor an application running in SF via AppInsights without a small amount of coding.

2. *Then, how to do it code based manner? Any reference to do code changes would be helpful.*

Here you go - [Monitor and diagnose an ASP.NET Core application on Service Fabric using Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-monitoring-aspnet).

3. *What is the difference between code less & code based monitoring? When to choose one over another? Our requirement is to study performance of application (deployed on various nodes of PROD service fabric cluster) under different load.*

As I said, to monitor your app you have to code. Although it's super simple. Other from that, here is a general recommendation - [Event analysis and visualization with Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-event-analysis-appinsights):

> **It is recommended to use EventFlow and WAD as aggregation solutions**,
>   because they allow for a more modular approach to diagnostics and
>   monitoring, i.e. if you want to change your outputs from EventFlow, it
>   requires no change to your actual instrumentation, just a simple
>   modification to your config file. **If, however, you decide to invest in**
>   **using Application Insights and are not likely to change to a different**
>   **platform, you should look into using Application Insights' new SDK** for
>   aggregating events and sending them to Application Insights. This
>   means that you will no longer have to configure EventFlow to send your
>   data to Application Insights, but instead will install the
>   ApplicationInsight's Service Fabric NuGet package.

Here is the link to the best practices - [Monitoring and diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-best-practices-monitoring) on SF platform.